# libcurl stuck after redirect fail

Tags: c, libcurl

I am using libcurl to get http pages and I'm stuck with a problem.
The page I am trying to get is: 
http://newsnow.in/news/tunisians-head-to-elect-president-in-runoff-u-t-san-diego

If you open the page you will receive an error stating that the page isn't redirecting properly. When I try to fetch it libcurl simply hangs, no error whatsoever. I also set the timeout which didn't work, I guess since it received the redirect message.
Here is my setting:

```
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://newsnow.in/news/tunisians-head-to-elect-president-in-runoff-u-t-san-diego"); // should be changed later with setLink()
    /* example.com is redirected, so we tell libcurl to follow redirection */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0");

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);

    /* send all data to this function  */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, filePtr);
```

And start it with the usual way:

```
res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

any ideas on what might solve the problem?

Comment: You can try to add [`CURLOPT_VERBOSE`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_VERBOSE.html) to let libcurl output more message to let you know what's going on.  Or you can just use `curl` the tool to get this URL and see what's going on.  If `curl` works fine, you can use `--libcurl FILE` option to let `curl` translate the options to code for you.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone encountering this problem in the future, following @SSC 's comment I added the verbose flag:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
```

And found out the page enters an infinite loop of redirects, this was easily solved using the max redirect flag:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 3L);
```